# Have SSH access - how to find domain?

Tags: url, ssh

I have been given SSH access to a server.  How do I know what URL to use to view my work?

Comment: should this be on serverfault.com?

Comment: You may want to explain your problem with a little bit more detail. SSH will give you (usually console) access to a machine, and there are no URLs involved.

Comment: Sadly that is all the detail I have.  (SSH access) - I can work on the server, but have no way of viewing any of my work in a browser without a URL to visit.

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig gives you an IP. else look under /etc/apache2/sites-available/ but if it is shared hosting, this could be quite intensive

Answer (score 0):

download [puTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and make ssh connection to ur machine, u can navigate through file system

Comment: your problem is not clear so my  ans may be in wrong direction